# Creating list in for loop in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I'm trying to create lists in R. But i got stuck.
Here's my R Code.

```
modellist_nnet <- list()
window_lengths <- c(50, 100)
for(i in 1:ncol(dep_var_normalized)) {
for (j in window_lengths){

knnGrid <- expand.grid(k = c(1, 2, 5, 10, 20))

timecontrol <- trainControl(method = 'timeslice', initialWindow = j, horizon = 1, summaryFunction=absretSummary, selectionFunction = "best", 
                          returnResamp = 'final', fixedWindow = TRUE, savePredictions = 'final') 
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)
set.seed(503)
variable_merge <- merge(dep_var_normalized[,i], indep_var_selected[[i]], all=F)
variable_merge <- as.data.frame(variable_merge)
modellist_nnet[[i]]<- train(variable_merge[,-1], variable_merge[,1], method = "knn", 
                           trControl = timecontrol, tuneGrid = knnGrid, preProcess = c('center', 'scale'))
stopCluster(cl)
cat("Window: ", j, "dep_var:", i)
}
}
```

I want to create a list("modellist_nnet") which contains the results of training.
the result of the posted codes only have window length 100("j") for each "i" 
Is there any possible way to create lists having both of window lengths("j")(50 ,100) for each "i"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list with one element per `i in dep_var_normalized`, where each element is another list that contains 2 items corresponding to each `j in window_lengths`. In code:

```
modellist_nnet <- list()
# New empty list
final_list <- list()
window_lengths <- c(50, 100)
for(i in 1:ncol(dep_var_normalized)) {
for (j in 1:length(window_lengths)){

knnGrid <- expand.grid(k = c(1, 2, 5, 10, 20))

timecontrol <- trainControl(method = 'timeslice', initialWindow = window_lengths[j], horizon = 1, summaryFunction=absretSummary, selectionFunction = "best", 
                          returnResamp = 'final', fixedWindow = TRUE, savePredictions = 'final') 
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)
set.seed(503)
variable_merge <- merge(dep_var_normalized[,i], indep_var_selected[[i]], all=F)
variable_merge <- as.data.frame(variable_merge)
# Here the index changes to "j"
modellist_nnet[[j]]<- train(variable_merge[,-1], variable_merge[,1], method = "knn", 
                           trControl = timecontrol, tuneGrid = knnGrid, preProcess = c('center', 'scale'))
stopCluster(cl)
cat("Window: ", j, "dep_var:", i)
}
final_list[i] <-modellist_nnet
}
```

If you want to access all the models corresponding to `window_length = 50`, you can use `lapply`:

```
model_window_50 <- lapply(final_list, function(x) x[[1]])
```

Likewise for `window_length_100`:

```
model_window_100 <- lapply(final_list, function(x) x[[2]])
```

Comment: I got some problem..."modellist_nnet[[j]]" produces the results at modellist_nnet[[50]], modellist_nnet[[100]]. And contains additional lists like modellist_nnet[[1]], modellist_nnet[[2]].. which have non values... How can i fix this problem?...

Comment: Uhmm did you modify the second for loop (along j) the way I did in my answer or did you keep your original version? It seems something related to how j is defined. (Notice I also changed accordingly the *initialWindow* parameter definition).

Comment: I modify my codes just like you told me. I guess modellist_nnet[[j]] creates 100 lists to produce modellist_nnet[[50]], modellist_nnet[[100]]..

Comment: Try moving `modellist_nnet <- list()` within the first for loop, i.e., immediately after `for(i in 1:ncol(dep_var_normalized))` and before `for (j in 1:length(window_lengths))`. See if it makes any change.